# errors C3293, C2227 when accessing to cell text

Tags: .net, ms-word, c++-cli, ms-office

When I trying to access cell's text in MS Word an error occur on build

```
Word::Documents^ pDocs = pWord->Documents;
Word::_Document^ pDoc = pDocs->Open( /* ... */ );
//...
MessageBox::Show(pDoc->Tables[1]->Cell(1,1)->Range->Text); //C3293, C2227
```

> error C3293: use 'default' to access the default property
>
> error C2227: left of '->Text' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

Can someone give me directions?

Comment: The property `Range` doesn't return a pointer?

Comment: @Joachim, I think no.
`Word::Cell^ cell = pDoc->Tables[1]->Cell(1,1);`
`Word::Range^ range = cell->Range;`
Doesn't work too, cuz same error on `Range`

Comment: Well, that's the cause of one of the errors. You can't use `->` on non-pointer structures.

Comment: But I think than error near `Cell` property.

Comment: Why `(((Microsoft::Office::Interop::Word::Range^)((cell)->Range)))->Text` works in watches window, but have an error on build: `error c3293: Range: ...`

Comment: Changed to `Word::Cell^ cell = pDoc->Tables[1]->Cell(1,1));` `Word::Range^ range = cell->default;` it's works. Watches window shows me `range->Text` with correct value but if I use `range->Text` in a program i've got `error C2872: Text: ambiguous symbol` and `error C2882: Text: illegal use of namespace identifier in expression`. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!
Here the solution:

```
Microsoft::Office::Interop::Word::Documents^ pDocs = pWord->Documents;
Microsoft::Office::Interop::Word::_Document^ pDoc = pDocs->Open( /* ... */ );
//...
Microsoft::Office::Interop::Word::Cell^ cell = pDoc->Tables[1]->Cell(1,1);
Microsoft::Office::Interop::Word::Range^ range = cell->default;
MessageBox::Show(range->default);
```

I shall be glad to hear other solutions without using 'default' property. I don't know why this property is only correct way to access 'Text' properties of 'Range', 'Selection' etc.